# How to find out if any point of a 2d line segment satisfies a system of linear inequations of degree 1 with one parameter?

Tags: inequality

Non formally, I want to know how to find out if a line segment intersects the area bounded by three axis-parallel lines. Line segment is not necessarily axis-parallel. I could always bruteforce a point if there weren't an infinity of them.

**Edit:** here's an example image for clarification. Black segments intersect the area, green segments don't.

[image: Insert geeky joke here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, we have a matrix $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times 2}$ and $v,w\in\Bbb R^{2},c \in \Bbb R^n$ and we need to know if the line segement $$s:[0,1]\to \Bbb R^2:t\mapsto v+wt$$ satisfies $As(t_0)\geq c$ for one $t_0\in [0,1]$. Here the inequality is taken component-wise and $A,c$ are chosen to describe the constraints (you want to know if $s(t)$ is in $\{x\mid Ax \geq c\}$). 
We treat three cases:

- If $As(0)\geq c$ then $t_0=0$
- If $As(1)\geq c$ then $t_0=1$
- If $As(0)\ngeq c$ and $As(1)\ngeq c$, note that $\require{cancel} As(t)\ngeq c \cancel{\iff} As(t)<c$ since we are working with component-wise inequalities. There is $t_0\in ]0,1[$ such that  $As(t_0)\geq c$ if and only if the constraints that were violated in $As(0)\ngeq c$ are now satisfied in $As(1) \ngeq c$. Formally, let $I_0 = \{i\mid (As(0))_i<c_i\}$ and $I_1 = \{i\mid (As(1))_i\geq c_i\}$. If $I_0 \subset I_1$, then such a $t_0$ exists.

**Edit:**(construction of the matrix $A$ and $c$)

If you have the system of inequalities
$$ a_{1,1}x+a_{1,2}y \geq c_1 \\ a_{2,1}x+a_{2,2}y \geq c_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,1}x+a_{n,2}y \geq c_n $$
It can be rewritten $$A\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix}\geq \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix}$$
With $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times 2}$ defined by $A_{i,j}=a_{i,j}$. In your example
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } c=\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ -8 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I don't see what's the matrix A for. Maybe I was unclear explaining the problem. Updated the question with an image, hope it is better than me at explaining things.

Comment: @Susei do my edit answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot, thanks. Heh, it's fascinating how elegant linear algebra is. I tried to implement my own solution for the problem, which seems to be right, but there were condition after a condition in a bunch of methods which looked awful even after refactoring. And it turns out to be just a couple of matrix operations. Too bad I'm quite helpless at math on my own : )

Comment: Wait a minute, if I understand it correctly, your answer is about finding if _all_ points of the segment are in the set. What I'm looking for is how to check if $$\exists t \in [0,1] : tAw\geq c-Av \quad $$ Or am I missing something and it somehow simply follows from your explanation?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it: I should find $t$ at the 3 intersections of the line with the bounding lines and apply those $t_i$ that are in $[0;1]$ to the inequality.

Comment: @Susei Sorry I misunderstood your question... there is a simpler way than finding the intersections... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Susei I adapted my answer and hope I'm now answering your question.

Comment: In $As(t_0)\geq 0$, did you mean $c$ instead of $0$? I don't see why there could be $0$.

Comment: @Susei yes you are right, it was a typo...